# how to select from bottom of the table

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting  some values from 3 different tables like,

```
$result=mysql_query("select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, c.order_date from party_details a, case_decision b, assign_advocate c where MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year' and a.partyid=b.party_id and a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1'");
```

But I want to select only 1 value from the bottom or say in descending order of table c (case_decision).

how can I do this. plz tell me. Thanx..

Comment: According to your code, table `c` is `assign_advocate`, not `case_decision`

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM table_list ORDER BY col_name DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

'order by' will sort based on the column
'desc' sorts in descending order

`$result=mysql_query("select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, c.order_date from party_details a, case_decision b, assign_advocate c where MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year' and a.partyid=b.party_id and a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1' order by a.party_name desc");`

Comment: I want to do some thing like that select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, c.order_date from party_details a, case_decision b, (assign_advocate c order by c.id desc limit 1) where MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year' and a.partyid=b.party_id and a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1'

Answer (score 0):

use `limit 1` after `order by your_column_name desc`

Answer (score 0):

Use [orderby](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause

Example (Syntax) :

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME ORDER BY YOUR_COL_NAME DESC LIMIT 1;
```

and in your case you should do like this :

```
$result=mysql_query("select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, 
c.order_date from party_details a, case_decision b, assign_advocate c where 
MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year' and a.partyid=b.party_id and 
a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1' **ORDER BY YOUR_COLOUM_NAME  DESC LIMIT 1** ");
```

Comment: I want to do some thing like that select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, c.order_date from party_details a, case_decision b, (assign_advocate c order by c.id desc limit 1) where MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year' and a.partyid=b.party_id and a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1'

Answer (score 0):

```
Please replce column name as per table design below statement :
```

$result=mysql_query("select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, 
    c.order_date from party_details a, case_decision b, assign_advocate c where 
    MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year' and a.partyid=b.party_id and 
    a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1' order by col_name  desc limit 1 ");

Comment: I want to do some thing like that select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, c.order_date from party_details a, case_decision b, (assign_advocate c order by c.id desc limit 1) where MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year' and a.partyid=b.party_id and a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1'

Answer (score 0):

You must replace `<column>` in query below with a reference to the column which you want the order be based on.

```
select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, c.order_date
from party_details a, case_decision b, assign_advocate c
where MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year'
and a.partyid=b.party_id and a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1'
order by <column> desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I want to do some thing like that select a.party_name, a.app_date, a.receive_date, a.case_type, c.order_date
from party_details a, case_decision b, (assign_advocate c order by c.id desc limit 1)
where MONTHNAME(b.date)='$month' and YEAR(b.date)='$year'
and a.partyid=b.party_id and a.partyid=c.party_id and c.status='1'

Comment: Just replace `<column>` by `c.order_date` in my query and try it. I think it will work as you want.